# Post the data in PHP MySql in Android

Tags: java, android, phpmyadmin

I want to post the data on PHP MySql via android application. When i run the application , my application is crashes and getting error like IllegalArgumentException for illegal character query.Can someone help me here .Thanks.

Here is my code

```
btnSubmitRequirment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit_Order);
btnSubmitRequirment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        strCustomerName = etCustomerName.getText().toString();
        strCustomerContact = etCustomerContact.getText().toString();
        strCurrentDate = "10-09-2014";
        System.out.println("strCurrentDate  = " + strCurrentDate);
        strProductQuantity = etProductQuantity.getText().toString().trim();
        strProductDeliveryDate = etProductDeliveryDate.getText().toString().trim();
        new SubmitOrder().execute();
    }

});

private class SubmitOrder extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Customer_Order_Detail.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Order..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... str) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String locationurl = "http://192.168.1.102/client_vendor_mgmt/order_insert.php?order_qty=strProductQuantity&order_delivery_date=strProductDeliveryDate&order_date=strCurrentDate&cust_name=strCustomerName&cust_contact=strCustomerContact&product_name=strSelected_Product";

        String url = locationurl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            System.out.println("new respos " + statusLine.getStatusCode() + " " + statusLine.toString());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // process execption }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // process execption }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Log.d("Data Post", " Successfully !!!");
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this and also

```
String locationurl="http://192.168.1.102/client_vendor_mgmt/order_insert.php?order_qty=4&order_delivery_date=9-12-2014&order_date=10-09-2014&cust_name=prathit &cust_contact=326457&product_name=KINGSTON 8 GB";

String url=locationurl.replaceAll(" ","%20");
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            try {

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                System.out.println("new respos "
                        + statusLine.getStatusCode() + " "
                        + statusLine.toString());

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }// process execption }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }// process execption }
```

Comment: @ra: Thanks for the reply.I'm not getting any error or exception but my record is not showing in PHP MySql server.

Answer (score 0):

You have space characters in the parameters of your url. For instance at index 137 tells your log. You can see the spaces too in the log. Just scroll to the right. Use `URLEncode.encode()` on your parameter string before sending. But the first space looks not intended.